# 'view' didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` - class based view

Tags: django

I am trying to access the posted form values in a class based Django view (UpdateView). I have it nearly working, but I am getting the error:

`The view maintenance.views.maintenanceEdit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

I have found many other posts having the same problem with a function based view, which `return render(request, 'template.html')` fixes the problem, but how can I do the same thing with a class based view?

my `views.py`:

```
class maintenanceEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView,):
    model = Maintenance
    form_class = EditMaintenance
    template_name = 'maintenance_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form,):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        complete = form.instance.completed
        super(maintenanceEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

In my `models.py` I have:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('equipmentdashboard',)
```

Which brings the user back to the correct page when the form is submitted. But now this is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to **`return`** the result from the `super()` call:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class maintenanceEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView,):
    model = Maintenance
    form_class = EditMaintenance
    template_name = 'maintenance_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('equipmentdashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form,):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        complete = form.instance.completed
        return super(maintenanceEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

That being said, Django will in case of a succesful POST return a redirect, to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You thus should specify a [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url).

Making an override like the one here is *not* useful, since you retrieve the `.completed` attribute, but you do nothing with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That fixed it.
I should have elaborated more, I plan on filling in a date field in my model if `.completed == True`, that is why I am doing this.
Does it make sense to do it here in my view? and if so, do I need the `reverse_lazy`  if I am using `absolute_url` in my model?

Comment: @MattG: you can do that in `form_valid` yes. I think it is here better to use `reverse_lazy(..)`, usually a `get_absolute_url` refers to a detail view of that object, the documentation says a "canonical identifier".

Comment: Ok I will implement your suggestion. Thanks again!